# For Each not looping on all sheets of a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to clean up and reshape multiple Excel files in a folder. My Excel files have at least 2 sheets in each or more. My transformation tasks are as follows:

1. To check each workbook if there is a sheet in it with the name "Block", if so, delete it;
2. To delete any hidden sheets;
3. Sheets with other names:
   3.1. Unmerge all cells of the sheets,
   3.2. Copy unmerged cell data of `UsedRange`,
   3.3. Special Paste/Transpose the copied data below the last used row of the same sheet,
   3.4. Delete the original data which was there before copying the `UsedRange`,
   3.5. Delete the columns starting from the 4th one until the column with specific header name

My problem is:

If there are more than one sheet in a workbook with the name "Block" (which needs to be deleted) or there are more than one sheet with different than "Block" names (which needs to be kept and transformed), the code stops its flow on that workbook and breaks. However, if I remove the last task (3.5 above) from the code, it goes smoothly or even with the last task (3.5) it still accomplishes the task if there is only one sheet with the name "Block" and one sheet with different name in a workbook. So, in my opinion, probably it is due to incorrect reference of `Lastcolumn` variable which I could not figure out how to correct it. My VBA code is similar to:

```vb
Public Sub preparereports()
    Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim MyFolder As folder
    Dim MySubfolder As folder
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set MyFSO = New FileSystemObject
    folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Value
    Set folder = MyFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    End With

    For Each wb In folder.Files
        If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
            For Each ws In masterWB.Worksheets
                If Left(ws.Name, 5) = "Block" Or ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
                    ws.Delete
                Else
                    ws.Cells.UnMerge
                    ws.Cells.ClearFormats
                    ws.UsedRange.Copy
                    Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ws.Range("A" & Lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    ws.Range("A1" & ":A" & Lastrow).EntireRow.Delete
                    Lastcolumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Write offs", ws.Rows(1), 0)
                    ws.Range(Cells(, 5), Cells(, Lastcolumn - 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
                 End If
            Next ws
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End If
    Next

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting your header row at `ws.Range("A1 & :A" & Lastrow).EntireRow.Delete` since you put your Lastrow to `.End(xlUp).row +1` so you copy paste the full UsedRange but delete the first line again with that.

Then Lastcolumn probably can't find Write offs because of that and can't delete anything properly.

This is what I use for Lastcolumn:

```
lColumn = wsA.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

But of course change your row deletion to if you want to keep your headers:

`ws.Range("A1 & :A" & Lastrow -1).EntireRow.Delete`

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank you, @Notus_Panda for reply, I am not deleting my header as I am not just copying/pasting but also transposing the data, so I checked again, after transpose, rows' contents are being column headers and that .End(xlUp).row +1 is deleting unnecessary row which is a row above the header row (of course after transposing)

Comment: My bad, didn't pay enough attention. Are you sure the last cell in A-column (of your original UsedRange) has "Write offs" then?

Comment: After hundreds of trials and errors, fortunately I found the solution, I modified "Lastcolumn" variable and the next line of the code as: Lastcolumn = ws.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
                    Range(ws.Columns(5), ws.Columns(Lastcolumn - 1)).Delete However, I could not figure out the main reason behind that why the previous "Lastcolumn" variable was not suit to the case.

Comment: Of course, I was forced not to search for a specific header name but use another row's content to find the last column which is not the ideal for my case.

Comment: I just re-tested your variant of "Write Offs" and deleting from the 5th column to wherever I had put "Write Offs" in the header. My hunch is that there isn't a "Write Off" in the second column (which becomes the first row after the deletion of the rows 1->Lastrow) in all of the sheets that you do things on. Match is case insensitive so it's either written wrong or not found in the second column/first row (depending when you view the data)

Comment: Thank you for your work @Noutus, on testing it. But, there is a "Write Off" text in the second columns (B column) in all of the sheets. I can send you my actual excel files if you like to see them

Comment: Sure, I can give them a look, your real issue isn't fixed after all.

Comment: As far as I know it is not allowed to upload files here, so I am not sure how to share them with you

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources should help with that

Comment: I am not sure Notus if I am properly sharing, please try the below link for my files https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0u5du1ag6reol0/Mock_VBA_Oybek.rar?dl=0

Comment: or try this: https://www.dropbox.com/t/dgmR7tjUV1ZlZFWb

Comment: Considering it was trying to mail something by simply trying to see the properties of `ws` when debugging the code, I'd place my bet there. It worked fine until it came to those problematic sheets.